# How can I put the 0 value at the end of the graph in my Rstudio graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have created a simple graph in RStudio with ggplot2 but when creating the graph the 0 value of the y axis was not placed at the end of the graph.
The result is that it looks like I have bars with values that do not exist.
Does anyone have an idea how I can get the y axis back?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzeVR.png)

The code i used looks like that

```
ggp3 <- ggplot(mysubset1, aes(`Storage number`,`Proteolysis Tests`, fill=`Volunteer number`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  labs(title = "Lipolysis Tests Results of S.aureus", 
       x ="Strain number", y = "Halo Measurment [mm]")

ggp3
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not really allowed to give out the data yet, as it is part of another publication. 
But it might help that most of the values are 0.

Comment: Your problem appears to be that Proteolysis is i  character format rather than numeric format. Try `subset1$Proteolysis <- as.numeric(subset1$Proteolysis)` and repeat your code.

Comment: Oh yes, you were right, I thought I had already done it numerically and I guess I missed it. Thanks a lot